# Is there a way to output results from a predefined function in javascript using firebug?

Tags: javascript

LIKE: I want to output this document.write("hello") or isNan(123). Is there any possibility to output this in the firebug?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `console.log` etc - see the [documentation](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel#Message_types)

Comment: i tried using console.log(isNan(123)) and got an error? can you explain why? cant seem to understand

Comment: Case sensitivity - i.e. should be `isNaN` - try `console.log(isNan(123))

Answer (score 1):

Use **console.log()** and [its related functions](https://getfirebug.com/logging). The results will show up in the Console tab.

```
console.log("Hello!");   // Hello!
console.log(isNaN(123)); // false
```

Comment: I tried using console.log(isNaN(123)); then got an error of ReferenceError: isNan is not defined

Comment: `isNan()` ***isn't*** defined. It's `isNaN()`, with the last N being uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

I know that in chrome i'm using

```
    console.log(myvariable)
```

And it show me the result in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Use console.log(), check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvaldez/h7E4W/) , here is an example:

```
var obj = new Object();
obj.greeting = 'hello'
obj.living = true;
obj.age = 33;
obj.gender = 'male';
obj.getGender = function() {
    return obj.gender;
};

console.log(obj.getGender()); // logs 'male'
console.log(obj.greeting); // logs hello
console.log(isNaN(obj.age)); // logs false
```

And here is the [documentation](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel#Console)